# How to detect if Blender is currently rendering

Tags: rendering, scripting, interface

I would like to hide certain parts of the UI automatically as soon as the user hits the Render Animation button.

I'm looking for something similar to `bpy.context.screen.is_animation_playing`  but specifically for Blender's render state. `is_animation_playing` does not evaluate to true if the scene is being rendered.

To detect if Blender is rendering we can set a Python property by attaching functions to the event handlers of `render_init`, `render_cancel` and `render_complete`. I have tested these, they work.

```
_state = {"is_rendering": False}

@persistent
def set_render_state_true(scene):
    _state['is_rendering'] = True

@persistent
def set_render_state_false(scene):
    _state['is_rendering'] = False

...   

bpy.app.handlers.render_init.append(set_render_state_true)
bpy.app.handlers.render_cancel.append(set_render_state_false)
bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.append(set_render_state_false)

...

if _state['is_rendering']:
    layout.label(text="This panel is disabled while rendering")
```

I'm wondering if there's a less bloaty way to detect this. A single property lookup would be great.